# .NET .application installer files?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I've seen popping up around the web recently .application files, for .NET installations. (Application manifests, per the extension details).

How exactly does one create these .application files in Visual Studio, and how do they differ from a standard windows setup? Please enlighten me.

I'm a C# developer, but never used a .application installer before.

Answer (score 9):

> How exactly does one create these .application files in Visual Studio?

**.application** file is automatically created when  you do a click-once deployment.

For click-once deployment, you can

- Right click on the project you want to release and choose *publish* menu item.

  -- or --
- Right click on the project, select properties, go to *publish* tab to publish.

> how do they differ from a standard windows setup?

You would create a standard windows setup program by creating a **setup project** in your solution.  And also they differ in a way that, for click-once, end-user does not have to install the program on their local machine.
You can learn more about differences between them from MSDN

- [Choosing Between ClickOnce and Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx)